# REMOVE SPECIFIC NUMBER WITH JS

Tags: javascript

I'M TRYING TO HANDLE THIS DATA IN JAVASCRIPT SO HOW CAN I REMOVE DATA ACCORDING TO THE ID NUMBER THE FIRST NUMBER

```
600030/01/2018/163904
600010/01/2014/3789
600030/01/2020/47104
600030/01/2012/39104
600010/01/2011/93817
```

how can i remove all 600030 data so i get

```
600010/01/2014/3789
600010/01/2011/93817
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you're starting from. Remove the data from what? Do you have an Array of strings? Array of array of numbers? Some HTML? Please post your code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all data shaped in Array and element is instance of String.

I would recommend Array.prototype.filter and String.prototype.startsWith();

```
let data = [
  '600030/01/2018/163904',
  '600010/01/2014/3789',
  '600030/01/2020/47104',
  '600030/01/2012/39104',
  '600010/01/2011/93817',
];

let filteredData = data.filter((d)=>!d.startsWith('600030'));

console.log( filteredData );
```

Result is

```
[ 
  '600010/01/2014/3789',
  '600010/01/2011/93817' 
]
```

Comment: And if is on a String variable, you only need to do a simple data.split('\n') before filtering